Как вынести логопас из кода на питоне в gitlab ci?
Пытаюсь вынести логин пароль для подключения к БД из кода программы на питоне в gitlab ci:
-python3 awr.py --user $USER --password $PASSWORD

В программе на питоне использую библиотеку argparse:
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--user', help='указать логин')
parser.add_argument('--password', help='указать пароль')
args = parser.parse_args()
.
.
.
def allConnect():

    print(f"Connection to {addressOracle}")
    cs = oracledb.makedsn(addressOracle, 1527, sid="XX")
    connection = oracledb.connect(
        user=args.user,
        password=args.password,
        dsn=cs
        #encoding="UTF-8"
    )
...

В итоге при отработке джобы получаю ошибку не верный логопас. Что делаю не так?

Если в логопасе есть спецсимволы, то в переменной CI/CD их надо экранировать. Например $. Если пароль "pa$$word", то в $PASSWORD надо указать "pa$$$$word". Если содержит символы, которые являются служебными для командной строки, то имеет смысл заключить их в кавычки или апострофы --user '$USER' --password '$PASSWORD'
